# Wrapping List.Item in TouchableRipple causes item to be read as "dimmed" by VoiceOver

Tags: react-native, accessibility, voiceover, react-native-paper

I have a React Native Paper `<List.Item>` wrapped by a RNP `<TouchableRipple>`. When wrapped with `<TouchableRipple>`, VoiceOver announces the item as "dimmed," signifying that it isn't clickable.

Does anyone know why this happens?

```js
      <TouchableRipple>
        <List.Item
          key={id}
          title={renderTitles}
          description={myDescription}
          onPress={() => onPress(option)}
          style={styles.listItem}
        />
      </TouchableRipple>
```

I've tried passing `accessibilityState={{disabled: false}}`, but it doesn't fix the issue. I've tried looking into `TouchableOpacity` as well, but it just looks like a `Pressable` wrapper around children; I don't see it altering `accessibilityState` or anything.

Interestingly, this doesn't occur in another location where I have a RNP `<Text>` element wrapped by a `<TouchableRipple>`, so I'm wondering if it's specific to `List.item`.